# Javascript Function Not Flattening Array Properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I put together a JavaScript function that is supposed to flatten a nested array. However, this method always just returns the original array. For example, running this function with the following array `[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6], [ ] ] ]` will just return that array. I know there are ways to do this with reduce, but what logical reason is preventing this method from working? `.map` should allow me to manipulate a return value and return that within the new array through the recursion call.

```
function mapper(array) { 
    return array.map((item) => {
        return (Array.isArray(item)) ? mapper(item) : item
    } 
)}
```

Comment: You are using map. Map returns an array of `n` elements. Use `.reduce` instead. 1 simple hack can be `var result = arr.toString().split(',')`

Comment: You're just mapping the array to itself, it's just going to return itself.

Comment: why is it mapping it to itself? it's recursively calling the function if it's an array that is supposed to be returning only a number not an array. the .reduce way of doing this has the same recursion call. .map should allow you to manipulate a return value and return that within the new array.

Comment: The logical reasoning that is preventing you from using `.map` is the fact that `map` is meant to return an array of n modified items. So you are not flattening anything. You can/are manipulating array.

Comment: For non-sparse arrays, `.map` always returns an array with the same number of elements as the original array. One element in the original array is mapped to one element in the result using the function.

Comment: the modified item is being returned through the recursion call. nowhere along is an array ever returned. if it's an array, it's called again recursively and only an item is returned.

Comment: That's not true. `.map` always returns an array. `mapper` always returns an array. You are returning an array from the function passed to `.map` with `mapper(item)`.

Comment: @Dog You are returning individual item but inside `.map` which parses return values and returns an array implicitly

Comment: i see! because .map is being called inside the recursion call it will return an array of the item. thank you!

Comment: @Rajesh–less code and more common is `var result = arr.slice('')`.

Comment: @RobG I'm not sure I understand but will it work for nested arrays?

Comment: @Rajesh—ah, good point. I thought you were just talking about individual arrays. But of course the array could contain strings with commas. How should elisions be treated? And empty arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what logical reason is preventing this method from working?

```
 var m = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6], []]];
 function mapper(array) { 
        return array.map((item) => {
            // for 1,2,3 it will return item
            // when it sees an array it will again call mapper & map
            // function will return a new array from it, so map on 
            // [4, 5, [6], []] will return a new array but will not take out
            // individual element and will put it in previous array

            return (Array.isArray(item)) ? mapper(item) : item
        } 
    )}
mapper(m)
```

map function does not mutate the original array but it will return a new array.

Comment: Yes that will also work. Along with `reduce` , `forEach`,`concat`,`spread operator` will also work

Comment: forEach doesn't work in that above iteration though, it just returns undefined when i set the iteration to a const and return it

Comment: with `forEach` you need to explicitly return

Comment: this gives me undefined though: function mapper(array) { 
    const newArray = array.forEach((item) => {
        return (Array.isArray(item)) ? mapper(item) : item
    })
    return newArray
}

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping the array to itself. Basically because map will return an array with exact same number of elements as the input. You cant expect it to return more, so you cant use it for flattening the array.

Should use reduce instead:

```
 function flatten(obj) {

     if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
          return obj.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(flatten(b)), []);
     } else {
          return [obj];
     }
 }
```

Comment: OP is not looking for alternatives. He/She is looking for explanation for *why map will not work*

Comment: why doesn't the recursion call within the ternary operation return a number instead of array would be a more accurate question.

Comment: Thank you. I just added the reason

Comment: but that's not the input. the recursion call is returning only numbers not arrays, but arrays still show up.

Comment: For example: The input has 5 elements then the result will has 5 elements, so no flattening